# 'Cannot read properties of undefined' of mongoose response object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below the mongoose Schema in node.js I am using:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: String },
    water: { type: Array },
    fertilizer: { type: Array }
})
```

And the following is the query that I made.
From POST request client side:

```
axios.post('/protected/main/getplantslist')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
```

to server side (node.js):

```
router.post('/main/getplantslist', (req, res) => {

    const sessionUserId = req.session.passport.user

    Plant.aggregate([{
        $facet: {
            waterPipeline: [
                {$match: 
                    {$and: 
                        [{userId: sessionUserId}]
                }}, 
                {$unwind: {path: "$water", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
                {$sort: {'water.date': -1}},
                {$group: {_id: '$_id', name:{$first: '$name'}, userId:{$first: '$userId'}, water:{$addToSet: '$water.date'}}},
                {$sort: {name: 1}}
            ],
            fertilizerPipeline: [
                {$match: 
                    {$and: 
                        [{userId: sessionUserId}]
                }}, 
                {$unwind: {path: "$fertilizer", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
                {$sort: {'fertilizer.date': -1}},
                {$group: {_id: '$_id', fertilizer:{$addToSet: '$fertilizer.date'}}},
                {$sort: {name: 1}}
            ]
        }
    }])
    .then(response => {
        res.send(response)
    })
})
```

I used facet in order to get two different aggregations and order the collections by two different date fields.

Here the response object that I get (which by the way is exactly what I need):

```
[{…}]
0:
fertilizerPipeline: Array(4)
0: {_id: '62b31bd642e3879a2bc014d6', fertilizer: Array(2)}
1: {_id: '629242c245908061eb0a58d9', fertilizer: Array(2)}
2: {_id: '6297676be803aada1b2fe47e', fertilizer: Array(0)}
3: {_id: '62ac4477a25a1208e29ff8b1', fertilizer: Array(0)}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
waterPipeline: Array(4)
0: {_id: '6297676be803aada1b2fe47e', name: 'crisantemo', userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716', water: Array(5)}
1: {_id: '62ac4477a25a1208e29ff8b1', name: 'melograno', userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716', water: Array(1)}
2: {_id: '62b31bd642e3879a2bc014d6', name: 'santoreggia', userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716', water: Array(2)}
3: {_id: '629242c245908061eb0a58d9', name: 'timo', userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716', water: Array(5)}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

but when I try to access (client side) the **waterPipeline** or **fertilizerPipeline** property like this:

```
response.data[0].fertilizerPipeline
```

I get this error:

> > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fertilizerPipeline')

According to similar topics, it seems that the problem resides in the mongoose Schema, since the new pipelines created through facet are not mentioned in it. I tried to adapt the Schema accordingly but still I get the same error. What I tried is:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: String },
    water: { type: Array },
    fertilizer: { type: Array },
    fertilizerPipeline: [{ type: Object }],
    waterPipeline: [{ type: Object }]
})
```

and others similar, but nothing seems to work.

How to fix this? Am I on the right path or the issue is something else?

Last info: I tried a much simpler query without facet and the response object I get works just fine.

Below the aggregate output from server:

```
{
  waterPipeline: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6297676be803aada1b2fe47e"),
      name: 'crisantemo',
      userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716',
      water: [Array]
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62ac4477a25a1208e29ff8b1"),
      name: 'melograno',
      userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716',
      water: [Array]
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62b31bd642e3879a2bc014d6"),
      name: 'santoreggia',
      userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716',
      water: [Array]
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("629242c245908061eb0a58d9"),
      name: 'timo',
      userId: '627154a5e1ba50ffac585716',
      water: [Array]
    }
  ],
  fertilizerPipeline: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62b31bd642e3879a2bc014d6"),
      fertilizer: [Array]
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("629242c245908061eb0a58d9"),
      fertilizer: [Array]
    },
    { _id: new ObjectId("6297676be803aada1b2fe47e"), fertilizer: [] },
    { _id: new ObjectId("62ac4477a25a1208e29ff8b1"), fertilizer: [] }
  ]
}
```

Comment: show how you are executing the query and then accessing the response. You are showing each part separately

Comment: console the response in the client side.

Comment: @turivishal the response object I display on client side is the one you see above

Comment: Can you post your exact code?, this can't be it.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert the exact code is hundreds of line on multiple files. How can I post all of it? I just posted the part that's not working. What key information is missing?

Comment: Well you're seeing the pipeline is working, so the issue must be somewhere else in the code you haven't posted. specifically on when you return values to the client

Comment: @Dema how are you sending the response to the client after the query, can show that part?

Comment: @turivishal on client side I'm using React. The lifecycle method componentWillMount triggers the axios POST request you see above. Server side, the aggregation is run (always above) and the response object is sent back (client side) to the axios POST request where is console (response.data). All data run through these two chunks of code.

Comment: Please post a copy of the aggregate output as a JSON - maybe a `console.log` on the server. A Mongoose's aggregate method returns an array as a result.

Comment: @prasad_ I've updated my question as you requested

Comment: What is `result` in the `result[0].fertilizerPipeline`?

Comment: @prasad_ `result` is a variable called in my web app to store the result object client side. You cannot see it from here since there's only part of the code. I will adjust my question

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because `result[0]` is undefined, so you cannot access `result[0].fertilizerPipeline`. Where do you assign `result` and why do you think it is an array?

If the `console.log(response.data)` shows what you stated, the way to access the first element is `response.data[0].fertilizerPipeline`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it is not the point of the question. No matter how I declare the object, I still cannot access his properties.